# How to send a forward slash using AHK

Tags: autohotkey

Easiest explained using code:

```
RAlt & a::{
RAlt & s::[
RAlt & d::]
RAlt & f::}
RAlt & r::/ ; Only one not working here. Pressing RAlt+r does nothing...
RAlt & t::\
```

All replacements except the one for the forward slash are working as expected.

I already tried the following:

- Bind `/` to a different hotkey like `RAlt & t` -> not working
- Bind something else to `RAlt & r`, e.g. `}` -> not working

--> It has nothing to do with the hot key `RAlt & r`, but with the replacement char `/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work, because the [remapping syntax](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm#Remap) doesn't release the <kbd>RAlt</kbd> key due to [internally using](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm#actually) the [blind](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm#Blind) send mode.
So, what happens is it sends the input required to generate the `/` key (whatever it may be on your keyboard layout, for me it is <kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd>), but on top of that, the <kbd>RAlt</kbd> key will also be held down.
On my keyboard layout this results in <kbd>RAlt</kbd> + <kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd>, which **does** actually work. So I guess you're not on my keyboard layout, haha.

So, to not have the <kbd>RAlt</kbd> held down during your input, you're going to want to make it be released.
The simplest way of doing this is using any of the [send commands](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm) without the blind mode. It'll automatically do the releasing for you.

I would of course recommend the [`SendInput`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm#SendInputDetail) send mode, due it being the most reliable and fastest.
And since two of your keys (`{` and `}`) have a special meaning in a send command, you're going to want to either [escape](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm#keynames) them (`{{}` and `{}}`), or use the [text mode](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm#Text). (And definitely not the [raw mode](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm#Raw), since it'll actually throw you out of the send input mode)

Also, as recommended in the documentation, don't use the [custom combination](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#combo) hotkey syntax if you can achieve your hotkey with the [modifiers](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#Symbols).
And in your case, you indeed can just use the modifiers:

- `>!r::` if your keyboard layout has an <kbd>RAlt</kbd> key
- `<^>!r::` if your keyboard layout has the <kbd>AltGr</kbd> key

Here's your finished script:
I went with escaping as opposed to the text mode, and assumed the <kbd>RAlt</kbd> key being present.

```
>!a::SendInput, {{}
>!s::SendInput, [
>!d::SendInput, ]
>!f::SendInput, {}}
>!r::SendInput, /
>!t::SendInput, \
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for this elaborate answer! Leaving all those direct links to the docs is really helpful & gives me a perfect opportunity to "dive into" some concept I wasn't even aware of until now!

Answer (score 1):

Try SendRaw: Similar to Send, except that all characters in Keys are interpreted and sent literally.

```
RAlt & a::SendRaw, {
RAlt & s::SendRaw, [
RAlt & d::SendRaw, ]
RAlt & f::SendRaw, }
RAlt & r::SendRaw, /
RAlt & t::SendRaw, \
```

Comment: You seem to be describing the [text mode](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm#Text), as opposed to the raw mode. In any case, it's redundant in 4 of the 6 cases there, and I'd recommend [`SendInput`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm#SendInputDetail) over it anyway.